# ado.net data service with mysql 6.2.3

Tags: mysql, odata

I'm using .Net 3.5 SP1. Just installed ADO.Net Data Service (ADO.NET Data Services Update for .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 )

I can successfully create Entities using ADO.Net Entity Framework. I'm following this article [Create OData Feed](http://marknic.com/2010/04/20/CreateAnODataFeedWithVS2008And2010.aspx). Instead of `config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);` I have `config.SetResourceContainerAccessRule("*", ResourceContainerRights.None);`.

But the end result is I can only see `<atom:title>Default</atom:title>`.

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the rights to None, then nobody can access anything on the service. As a result all the entity sets are hidden and that's why you see nothing in the service document.
The data service hides entity sets and types which are not accessible (behaves as if they don't exist).
You need to allow access to at least something in order to use the service.

Comment: that's a typo, it needs to be ResourceContainerRights.AllRead. But I still get the same result.